# How many relations are there on a set with n elements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

`Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 8th Edition by Kenneth Rosen` states the following on Pg 600:

> ...a binary relation from A to B is a set R of ordered pairs, where the
> first element of each ordered pair comes from A and the second element
> comes from B.

So if A has 3 elements and B has 3 elements, the binary relation should have 3 * 3 = 9 elements.

Now let us consider the case where we have a binary relation from A to itself.  In this case also I expect the binary relation to have 3 * 3 = 9 elements.

However, on Pg 602 the author states that:
[image]

I am quite confused by this and would appreciate any clarification.

Comment: The relation could have $0$ elements or $1$, etc. up to $9 = |A| \times |B|=|A \times B|$. $\{(a,b)\}$ is a valid relation.

Answer (score 1):

This is where you went wrong. "So if $A$ has $3$ elements and $B$ has $3$ elements, the binary relation should have $3 * 3 = 9$ element."
It is not the binary relation that should have $9$ elements; it's the product $A\times B$ that has $9$ pairs (if both sets $A$ and $B$ have $3$ elements each).
Further, a relation is a subset of this $A\times B$ product. And since the $A\times B$ product that is made up of $9$ pairs has $2^9$ subsets, each subset is a unique relation, hence $512$ possible subset/relations.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a set with $n$ elements. Then $A\times A$ has $n^2$ elements.

What you consider is the set of all binary relations $R$ on $A^2$. These relations are exactly the elements of the power set of $A^2$. The cardinality of the power set of $A^2$ is $2^{n^2}$, as requested.

Comment: So does $A\times B$ have $2^{m*n}$ relations, if cardinality of A is m and that of B is n (and not m * n, as I am assuming)?

Comment: Indeed, the power set of set with $N$ elements has $2^N$ elements.