# Definition of binary relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

**Addendum:**
(For the benefit of future confused novices like me)

I received some excellent comments/responses to my query.  The comment that finally clear the cloud of ignorance from my mind was [this comment by Sangchul Lee](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4305751/definition-of-binary-relation#comment8969349_4305751).

---

**Original Post:**
This post is a follow-up to my [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4305744).  Based on the [response](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4305745/956241) that I have received so far, I wonder whether the correct definition for binary relation should be:

*...a binary relation from A to B is a set R of ordered pairs, where the first element of each ordered pair comes from the power set of A and the second element comes from the power set of B.*

instead of the following definition,

> ...a binary relation from A to B is a set R of ordered pairs, where the
> first element of each ordered pair comes from A and the second element
> comes from B.

as given in `Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 8th Edition by Kenneth Rosen` on Pg 600:

---

Comment: Sounds like the same thing to me. $A$ and $B$ in the _Discrete Math_ book could themselves be powersets.

Comment: No, the definition in the textbook is correct. A relation $R$ from $A$ to $B$ is a subset of $A\times B$, not a subset of $\mathcal{P}(A)\times\mathcal{P}(B)$. But it is true that A relation $R$ from $A$ to $B$ is an *element* of the power set $\mathcal{P}(A\times B)$ (which is of course the same as telling that $R \subseteq A\times B$).

Comment: The subsets of $A^2$ are exactly the relations from $A$ to $A$, that's why the cardinality of a powerset (specifically of $A^2$) was calculated.

Comment: @SangchulLee if binary relation from A to B has to take 1 element from A and 1 element from B, and A has cardinality m while B has cardinality n, how many relations are there in the binary relation?  I thought it was m * n but apparently it is is $2^{m*n}$

Comment: As in my comment, a binary relation from $A$ to $B$ is a subset of $A\times B$, so you have to count the number of subsets of $A\times B$. Now if $\operatorname{card}(A)=m$ and $\operatorname{card}(B)=n$, then each of the $mn$ possible pairs $(a, b)$ in $A\times B$ can be an element of a relation or not. So each pair gives two possibilities, hence the total number of relations is $2^{mn}$. It might help you understand this to play with a toy case: $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{x,y\}$ and try to list all the possible relations from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: @SangchulLee please provide me some more guidance.  I see the possible relations only as the ordered pairs (1, x), (1, y), (2, x), (2, y).

Comment: @Sandeep a relation is a set of ordered pair, so {(1,x)} is a relation. It means 1~x and nothing else. {(1, x), (1, y), (2, x), (2, y)} is another relation, it means 1~x,1~y,2~x,2~y. (a~b means a is related to b). {(1,y),(2,x)} is another relations which means 1~y, 2~x. You can build 2^4=16 subsets that contain these tuples, so there are 16 relations that you can define

Comment: Relations are *subsets* of $A\times B$, not elements of $A\times B$. So, here the complete list of $2^{2\times2}=16$ relations from $\{1,2\}$ to $\{x,y\}$: \begin{gather*}\varnothing=\{\},\\\{(1,x)\},\quad\{(1,y)\},\quad\{(2,x)\},\quad\{(2,y)\},\\ \{(1,x),(1,y)\},\quad \{(1,x),(2,x)\},\quad \{(1,x),(2,y)\},\\ \{(1,y),(2,x)\},\quad \{(1,y),(2,y)\},\quad \{(2,x),(2,y)\}, \\ \{(1,x),(1,y),(2,x)\},\quad\{(1,x),(1,y),(2,y)\},\\\{(1,x),(2,x),(2,y)\},\quad\{(1,y),(2,x),(2,y)\},\\\{(1,x),(1,y),(2,x),(2,y)\}\end{gather*}

Comment: @SangchulLee *Relations are subsets of A×B, not elements of A×B*  ---- that's a very profound statement that I just had not realized before.  I think I finally get it.

Comment: very profound it is not, it's just a definition. But maths starts at using the right definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The definition in the text book is totally correct. Your modification is nonsense: a pair is a set of *elements*, not *subsets*. So leave the powersets of $A$ and $B$ out of it. A relation is a subset of $A \times B$, so by definition we *do* have $R \in \mathscr{P}(A \times B)$.

Comment: I fail to see why the binary relation from A to B would have $2^{m*n}$ elements if the cardinality of A is m and the cardinality of B is n.  Kindly advise.

Comment: The **set** of **all** relations from $A$ to $B$ has size $2^{m\times n}$, but such  a relation itself could have no elements at all. Or just $1$. You probably misunderstood the statement. @Sandeep

Comment: @Sandeep In $C=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\ldots,\}$ each *element* of $C$ has size $1$ but $C$ is infinite even. There is a difference between size of the elements of a set and the size of the set.